How to add name of container to logs by fluent-bit
I have a docker (no K8s). There are some logs. I collect it with fluent-bit.
[INPUT]
  Name               tail
  Path               /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log
  mulriline.parser   docker

[FILTER]
  Name               record_modifier
  Match              docker.*
  Record             hostname ${HOSTNAME}

config
My config add to the log hostname. And it show in log big container ID.
I understand that I can match ID and Name by my hands. But I think there is more simple way.
Some HELP please.

Please attach your config to your post as a code, not as an image

Also make sure you're asking about programming specifically on Stack Overflow.  For system-administration questions like configuring log collectors, another site like [devops.se] or [sf] might be more appropriate.

@poisoned_monkey done

@David Maze thanks, I'm try to ask there

You can use Docker Input Plugin for this purposes and enable Docker_Mode. It will also retrieve container name
[INPUT]
  Name                docker
  Path                /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log
  Tag                 docker.*
  Docker_Mode         true

[FILTER]
  Name                record_modifier
  Match               docker.*
  Record              hostname ${HOSTNAME}


It doesn't work. Unknown configuration property 'path'. Also in documents there no property as 'path' for docker type.
